# attatching a value to an array with a datapanel "item" as index in Python

Tags: python, string, indexing, panel

essentially I want to attach a value to an array, indexing at the same time with, as index, the name of the "item" of the data panel. when looking at the code

```
#Scoring1[item] = 10 - max(ticker_2,ticker_1)


Scoring1 = []
series = pd.Panel.fromDict(series_col)

for item in series:
# f_cls = mp_thr[row["cls"]]
# thresholdSTABILE = mp_thr[cls][0]
thresholdSTABILE = 0.01

for j, p in enumerate(PercentiliUp):
       if np.nanmean(series[item]['Ret']) + thresholdSTABILE > np.nanpercentile(series[item]['Ret'], p):
            ticker_1=j

for j, p in enumerate(PercentiliDown):
        if np.nanmean(series[item]['Ret']) - thresholdSTABILE < np.nanpercentile(series[item] ['Ret'], p):
            ticker_2=j

#Scoring1[item] = 10 - max(ticker_2,ticker_1)
```

nothing seems to work. i get the:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

which I kind of get since I'd like to turn the "item" in a string as index, but I have been unable to do so.

in the hope that I could explain myself, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

sorry to have bothered you but I asked due to time sensitive constraints on a project. I found the solution, I just turned Scoring1 into a dictionary